# Jquery, ajax post and get results?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, post, get

I am making a login, I want ajax to post each key stroke to the query. When the login matches a login in the database (mySQL), I want the password to be returned back to the parent page. That is all for now. I have in the past used ajax to post php to databases, but never had to return a variable back. I also do not know if I am passing the form info over, thanks!

index.php script:

```
$(function(){

    $("#inputEmail").keyup(function() {
    var UsernameInput = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PullUserDb.php",
            data: { 'UsernameInput':UsernameInput },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data)
            {
            $('.body').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

index.php HTML:

```
 <div class = "HeaderLogin">
        <form class="LoginForm">
            <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input style = "height: 30px" type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <input style = "height: 30px" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button style = "width: 200px" type = "button" class="SubmitLogin">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PullUserDb.php:

```
<?php
//Connect to the server
$db_server = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
?>

<?php
//Connect to the database
mysql_select_db('databases')
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
?>

<?php
$Input_Username = $_POST['UsernameInput'];
//Pull columns and store them into variables
$query_users = "Select *

                FROM users

                WHERE Username = '".$Input_Username."'";

$result_users = mysql_query($query_users);
if (!$result_users) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

while($row_user_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result_users))
   {
        $Username = $row_users_fetch['Username'];
        $Password = $row_users_fetch['Password'];
        $Email = $row_users_fetch['Email'];
        echo $Email;
   }
?>
```

Comment: If you mean that you intend to pass the password around in plain-text, please don't do that. Proper login systems encrypt supplied passwords and compare them to encrypted values in the database. You should never pass credential information from the server to the client if you can avoid it.

Comment: I realize there is security issues here. I am just trying to get the functionality down first. I'll figure out encryption later. This is just a personal project FWIW.

Comment: I could also send back a true or false. I am ok with that as well. I just want to return something back.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget which does precisely what you are asking for?  http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I could use a widget, but this is just a personal project. I am trying to learn, so I am doing everything by hand....well atleast this part I would like too. All I need is somthing returned from ajax. ANYTHING. lol

Comment: I figured it out. My inputEmail is a ID not a class. It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT! THIS CODE HAS BEEN EDITED TO SHOW OTHERS WHO NEED IT! THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL ECHO THE EMAIL OF THE CORRESPONDING USER TO THE BODY CLASS DIV WHEN YOU ENTER A GOOD USERNAME.